# Have traditional categories such as phylum, class, genus, been dispensed with in modern taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, phylogenetics, nomenclature, classification

Looking through the one zoom and EOL projects I see no reference to such categories.

Comment: We still use these concepts because they help communication but they are mainly arbitrary. Some of the discussion [in this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species/39669#39669) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks Remi, is there scope for a listing of species in terms of supersets and subsets - most likely from an evolutionary perspective.  If this has been done do you know where I could see some examples.    I don't have the required knowledge to give a detailed example but something along the lines of lion<feline<carnivore<mammal<vetebrate<chordate<etc might be one.

Comment: I am afraid any categorization of lineages of this kind will necessarily end up being somewhat arbitrary. I could picture categorizing into a <enter taxonomic level; e.g. family> everything that share a common ancestor less than <enter number> years ago. It would still lead to issues with horizontal gene transfer but that might be feasible.

Comment: But presumably some worthwhile subsets / supersets can be shown particularly from a structural point of view.   Again I lack knowledge here but I am guessing that a term like feline is arbitrary but mammal and invertebrate are demonstrable and also that all mammals are invertebrates.  Am I on solid ground with that?

Comment: Oh yes of course. What I meant is whether we choose to call mammals a class or an order is somewhat arbitrary. But we can clearly define monophyletic taxa and investigate their relationship to other monophyletic taxa. [This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist/52729) that offers an intro to phylogeny might be of interest to you